# Google Spreadsheet: Display text with game specific commands in separate window/cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a google spreadsheet with different dialog texts which are going to be imported into a game. The game's dialogs use game specific simple emoji-commands that are applied in the game, like "" which gives red color to the next letters and "" which stops the color. Or ⤴️ which enlarges the next letters.

Would it be possible, perhaps using a plugin, to automatically calculate these commands from the cells with the dialogs and display the result in another cell or window?
Something like this:

[image]

And would it also be possible to display these texts in front of an image, so that i can see how the texts would fit in the speech bubbles of the game?
Something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Hi, I'm voting to close this question as I think it is too broad. Consider focusing your questions on single specific issues, and provide enough information for users to easily understand your situation.

Comment: Hi, ok I understand. Yes my question was a bit too badly described, so now I have revised it a bit.
In short, I'm asking if it's possible to execute and display simple game-specific color and size commands in an extra cell so I can see how these texts would look in my game.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Would it be possible, perhaps using a plugin, to automatically calculate these commands from the cells with the dialogs and display the result in another cell or window?`, I think this goal can be achieved by Google Apps Script. About `And would it also be possible to display these texts in front of an image, so that i can see how the texts would fit in the speech bubbles of the game?`, I cannot understand what you want to do from this. So, unfortunately, I cannot answer it. I apologize for this.